# jQuery's Less Than Selector, Treating Each Child Differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors, screen-scraping

I am trying to select the first six divs in a structure like the following, using this command:

```
$('#alpha > .bet.gimmel > div :lt(6)').each(function(){
    //code here
}
```

To my understanding, this code is first targeting the div whose id="alpha," then I am specifying its child node whose classes match "bet," and "gimmel", and then choosing the first six children. My question is now that I have the subset I want to play around with, how can I say do x to the first div, do y to the second div, etc. My goal is to grab the text, as described below, so any help is much appreciated.

The format of the HTML I am interested in is the following. Please note that this information is nested with 5 or 6 other divs, tho I do not believe I need to specify it all: 
    
        
            
                 TEXT_1 
            
            
                
                
 TEXT_2 
            
            ... around 10 times
        
    
**Somewhat related part II:** Although it probably is not as efficient, can I just copy the XPath of the text I want via Chrome's Developer Tools, then paste it into

```
$(theXPath).show();
```

**This is what my code looks like so far:**

```
function getData() {
    $('#ext-gen56 > .identify.multiline > div:lt(6)').each(function (i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $(this).text();
        } else if (i == 1) {
            $(this).text();
        } else {
            $(this).text();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there should be no gap between the selector where you specify the index

```
$('#alpha > .bet.gimmel > div:lt(6)')
```

While iterating over the elements using `$.each` use the index that is passed to the function

```
$('#alpha > .bet.gimmel > div:lt(6)').each(function(i) {

      if(i ===0) {
          /// do something
      }
      else if (i ===1 ) {
          /// do something else
      }
      ...
      ...
});
```

**Update**

Looks like a syntax error to me

```
      else {
          $(this).text();
      }

   }  < -- End of each
}  < -- En of function
```

Supposed to be

```
      else {
          $(this).text();
      }

   });  < -- End of each
}  < -- En of function
```

Comment: hi @Sushanth, thank you for your suggestion. However, I encounter a Parse Error upon executing just the first part ($'#alpha...{}). Also when I seek to extract the text from a certain part of a div, would I (for the first piece of text, just do "$this.text();"?

Comment: Can you pass an example of what you were trying

Comment: I should have seen that, that was terrible on my end. Tho I have some error with injectin jquery, you answered my question!

Comment: @jsc123.. Glad to have helped.. Happens with everyone though.. :)